# Set the download directory in Google Chrome via a .bat file or selenium

Tags: python, bash, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I need to set a unique download directory for a specific profile in Google Chrome, not manually, but through the command line or in another way.
ChromeOptions I used:

```
options.add_argument('--allow-profiles-outside-user-dir')
options.add_argument('--enable-profile-shortcut-manager')
options.add_argument(rf'user-data-dir=C:\User')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
```

I tried to write the script myself, but nothing worked. I didn’t find the required line with the download directory in the chrome preferences file. Maybe I was looking in the wrong place.
Also I tried `options.add_argument(f"download.default_directory={download_path}")` *but that didn't work either.*

Example script:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Path\To\Your\Custom\Profile" --download.default_directory="C:\Path\To\Your\Download\Directory"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `add_experimental_option()` with `"prefs"` to set the download directory.

This combination of preferences worked for me: (Set `DOWNLOAD_PATH` first.)

```py
from selenium import webdriver

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": DOWNLOAD_PATH,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "default_content_setting_values.notifications": 0,
    "default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "managed_default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting": 1,
    "profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1,
}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```